# division of bigdecimal by integer

Tags: java, android, division, bigdecimal

I want to divide a bigdecimal value with an integer.i have rounded the bigdecimal value(if it is 133.333 then rounded value is 133).given below is my code snippet.

```
v1 = v1.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
int temp = BigDecimal.valueOf(v1.longValue()).divide(constant1);
```

value of constant is 12. It is showing an error message that

> The method divide(BigDecimal) in the type BigDecimal is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Can anyone help me to do the division?

Comment: i am stuck on this....please anybody tell me wat to do... :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change

```
.divide(constant1);
```

to

```
.divide(new BigDecimal(constant1));
```

---

Btw, why don't you just do something like

```
int temp = (int) (Math.round(v1.doubleValue()) / constant1);
```

??

Comment: i tried this...but now it is showing that i have to change the datatype of temp as bigdecimal.

Comment: right, so append `.intValue()` on the end of the line then if you don't want to do this.

Comment: since the wanted result (apparently) is an `int`, better do `int temp = Math.round(v1.longValue()) / constant1;`, or?

Comment: Sure. Assuming you intended to write `doubleValue`, you need a cast for that line to compile though

Comment: i cant change the datatype of temp.bcz it is using somewhere else

Comment: Try my last (updated) line. `temp` is an `int`, and I believe it performs the same operation.

Comment: actually I intended to write `floatValue` so no cast needed at all (BTW if you do not use @Carlos in the comment-answer I will not be notified...)

Answer (score 0):

You should write the code as follows:

```
int temp = BigDecimal.valueOf(v1.longValue())
        .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(constant1)).intValue();
```

The thing about BigDecimal and BigInteger is that they mostly operate with instances of these classes and not with primitive types. Results of operations are also new instances of these classes.

One other remark: I advise to use `valueOf` static method instead of a constructor, because by doing this you may have a possibility to avoid creation of new objects. Using a constructor makes creation of a new object explicit, which is not necessary in this case at all.

Comment: i am getting this exception when i tried this code10-19 16:28:42.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(479): java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591206/non-terminating-decimal-expansion-no-exact-representable-decimal-result , it is shown there how to avoid such errors by using rounding.