# BigDecimal math operations

Tags: java, object, bigdecimal

I want to write this in Java but I get some errors and I am not sure how to write it:

```
C = A - (A*B)/100
```

All of my values are defined as Bigdecimal objects.

I tried something like this but is not working:

```
C = A.subtract(A.multiply(B).divide(100));
```

..I get a warning to add more arguments to the divide method. I do not know how to write it correctly. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: relevant [javadoc pages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: You are getting the warning "The method divide(BigDecimal) in the type BigDecimal is not applicable for the arguments (int)". Not that you should add more arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [division of bigdecimal by integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819553/division-of-bigdecimal-by-integer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BigDecimal` has no `divide(int)` method, but that's what you're asking it to do with `.divide(100)`, because `100` is an `int` literal. If you refer to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/math/BigDecimal.html), all of the `divide` methods accept `BigDecimal` instances.

You can use [`divide(BigDecimal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-) instead, by using [`BigDecimal.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-long-):

```
C = A.subtract(A.multiply(B).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)));
```

(It accepts a `long` [or `double`], but `int` can be promoted to `long`.)

Alternately, for some values, you might use the `String` constructor instead:

```
C = A.subtract(A.multiply(B).divide(new BigDecimal("100")));
```

...particularly if you're dealing with floating-point values that might lose precision in `double`. `100` is fine for `valueOf`, though.

Comment: This is a good way to do it, but I would change the 100 to BigDecimal.valueOf(100.0).

Comment: @MiguelMunoz - Why?

Answer (score 1):

```
c = a.subtract(a.multiply(b).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100.0)));
```