# What causes "Non-terminating decimal expansion" exception from BigDecimal.divide?

Tags: java, exception, bigdecimal

I've used BigDecimals before but not very often and I was working on something this morning and I kept getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion;
no exact representable decimal result.
    at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1594)
```

I was attempting to set the scale and use rounding to eliminate the problem like so:

```
    BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(1131).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(365).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal bd3 = bd1.divide(bd2).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    System.out.println("result: " + bd3);
```

However, I keep getting the same exception. Anyone able to show me where I have made a mistake?

Comment: Which line triggers the exception?

Comment: @m0skit0 `at java.math.BigDecimal.divide` shows the exception location

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591206/non-terminating-decimal-expansion-no-exact-representable-decimal-result

Answer (score 76, accepted):

## Non-terminating decimal need rounding

When using [`divide`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal,java.math.MathContext)) you should use a [`MathContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/MathContext.html) with [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html) in case the exact result has an infinite number of decimals.

Such is your case:

```
MathContext mc = new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP) ;
BigDecimal bd3 = bd1.divide(bd2, mc);
```

Alternatively call [`divide`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal,java.math.RoundingMode)) with a rounding mode to use the scale of the numerator (`bd1` in the example below):

```
BigDecimal bd3 = bd1.divide(bd2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem. I had tried using a MathContext also but it looks like I did that incorrectly.

Comment: I like the fact that you showed both ways.  At first I thought, why would anyone ever use the `MathContext`.  Then it dawned on me.   Duh... for consistency...

Comment: I do `new BigDecimal(350000.00).divide(new BigDecimal(1))` and I still get the "Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result" exception. I don't understand why the result is not simply 350000, can you elaborate please ?

Comment: @DavidHofmann That line returns 350000 as expected... I suggest you ask a separate question with a complete example that shows your problem.

Comment: You say an alternative is to call divide with a scale and rounding mode, but in your example you don't actually show a scale value being passed.

Comment: @Michael the scale of bd1 is used (see the javadoc by clicking on the link). I will clarify.

Comment: @assylias Thanks for the information. The JavaDoc actually mentions this but when I read it the first time it didn't immediately jump out at me what it meant, it makes sense now: "whose value is (this / divisor), and whose preferred scale is (this.scale() - divisor.scale());"

Answer (score 4):

Here's the problem

```
bd1.divide(bd2)
```

You need to use one of the overloaded `divide()` methods that takes a rounding mode (in various forms) - you cannot do the rounding after the division because with a nonterminating fraction the intermediate result would either already need to be rounded, or require infinite storage space.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by an operation (division) that would result in a recurring decimal.

The solution is to specify a *scale* when performing a division, for example:

```
BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal("1");
BigDecimal three = new BigDecimal("3");
BigDecimal oneDivThree = one.divide(three, 200, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because of the division:

1. The BigDecimal by default always tries to return the exact result of an operation.
2. Due to this, certain division operations like 1 divided by 3, the exact quotient will have an infinitely long decimal expansion. This will cause the division operation to fail and throw the error as described above.

Provide a scale and a rounding mode (as you've done when creating the BigDecimals) within the division method to prevent this.

Taken from [here](http://jaydeepm.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/bigdecimal-and-non-terminating-decimal-expansion-error/). Example code for working division is also provided.

See also: [Java docs on BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: Seemed to not be your words, so I googled it, and found this.  http://jaydeepm.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/bigdecimal-and-non-terminating-decimal-expansion-error/  Lol.

Comment: @Vulcan they are not, but I always link to sources. Simply making the answer complete first. Most good answer will be quotes.

Comment: Isn't it the scale, not the RoundingMode, that fixes the problem?

Comment: @NeilCoffey Yes, that's correct. I'll edit.

Comment: @Keyser Understanable, I just am not completely sure of any plagiarism-related code of conduct on here, so I provided the link for everyone's sake.

Comment: @Vulcan When providing sources I think it should be encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

By default, BigDecimal attempts to return the exact value of the given division expression.  Because of this, if the exact value cannot be determined due to an infinite decimal expansion, an ArithmeticException is thrown.  A basic example of this is dividing 1 by 3, resulting in one third, a value which cannot be represented exactly in decimal notation.

Answer (score 0):

To fix, you should change the third stament as follow:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(1131).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(365).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
BigDecimal bd3 = bd1.divide(bd2, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
System.out.println("result: " + bd3);
```