# "Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result" happens even when divide by 100

Tags: java, bigdecimal, arithmeticexception

My java code is running on HP-UX hpdev B.11.23 U ia64 and sometimes it will produce the following exception:
java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.

The code that causes it:

```
BigDecimal p_Change = (BigDecimal)record.get("P_CHNG");
p_Change.divide(new BigDecimal(100));
```

record is simple a Collection of column values from a sql query.p_change comes from a table in an Oracle database where the column is NUMBER(10,2).

I understand why this happens.The frequency is random, it will divide fine with the same data sometimes. I am just wondering if this has something to do with the hardware.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591206/arithmeticexception-non-terminating-decimal-expansion-no-exact-representable

Comment: if this is currency, why not just use integers?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do a system.out on your value for p_Change?

```
BigDecimal p_Change = new BigDecimal(Math.PI);
System.out.println(p_Change.divide(new BigDecimal(100)));

// yields this 0.03141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
```

It's identical to your code, with just the substitution of p_Change with pi

The issue probably has to deal with you not entering a rounding mode. Try using

```
p_Change.divide(new BigDecimal(100), BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```