# In java, how do I divide two BigIntegers and store the value in a double?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to divide two BigIntegers 22 and 7. In other words, I'm trying to store the first few decimals of `b1.divide(b2)` [where `b1 = new BigInteger("22")`, and `b2 = new BigInteger("7")`] into some datatype. However, if I use a `BigDecimal`, it shows an irrepresentable number error, while it doesn't even work for doubles. What should I do? For your convenience, here's the code:

```
BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("22");
BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger("7");
BigInteger b3 = b1.divide(b2);
System.out.println(b3);
```

And here's what shows up in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decima
l expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
    at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(Unknown Source)
    at Divider.main(Divider.java:13)
```

Comment: why not use BigDecimal?

Comment: Your code is working using java7

Comment: Your code example only shows `BigInteger` objects... but your exception trace references `BigDecimal`, so there is something you aren't telling us.

Comment: The code you have given is using `BigInteger`, whereas the exception you mentioned is showing `BigDecimal`, which means the exception belongs to some other code, not the posted one.

Comment: I'm SOO Sorry guys. I meant `BigDecimal b3` , and not `BigInteger b3` . So sorry for giving you guys all that trouble. Thanks for answering my intended question nonetheless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `BigInteger.divide(...)` will give `BigInteger` only, so you will loose the precision of the output if you use this method directly. Below are some solutions.

**Solution 1 (using `BigInteger`):**

```
    BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("22");
    BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger("7");
    double d = b1.doubleValue() / b2.doubleValue();
    System.out.println(d);
```

**Solution 2 (using `BigDecimal`, already defined precision)**

```
    BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal("22");
    BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal("7");
    BigDecimal b3 = b1.divide(b2, MathContext.DECIMAL32);
    System.out.println(b3);
```

**Solution 3 (using `BigDecimal`, self controlled precision)**

Refer solution given by Jason Hoetger

Comment: If `b2` is much larger than `b1`, `b1.doubleValue() / b2.doubleValue()` will return 0 much sooner than if you do the division on the big integers (in a way that understands big integer division) before converting the result to a double.

Answer (score 2):

BigInteger.divide() returns a BigInteger, so you're not going to be able to get "the first few decimals" of any result of BigInteger.divide() unless it is actually an integer.

If `b1` and `b2` absolutely must be BigIntegers, you can create a BigDecimal from your BigInteger, then use BigDecimal.divide(). You'll need specify the scale of the result in order to control the number of decimal places, as well as a MathContext to determine how to round the answer. For example:

```
BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("22");
BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger("7");
BigDecimal quotient = new BigDecimal(b1)
    .divide(new BigDecimal(b2), 3, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
System.out.println(quotient);
```

Results in:

```
3.143
```

Comment: Why bother using BigInteger in the first place?

Comment: @ScaryWombat In this contrived example it doesn't make much sense, but in a more realistic situation you may have no choice, for example if the BigIntegers are coming from another API.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to divide BigInteger b1 by b2 and store it in a BigInteger. However, the quotient of two integers is an integer.

3.14286 (rounded) is not an integer.

You can use `BigDecimal` instead:

```java
BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("22");
BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger("7");
BigDecimal b3 = new BigDecimal(b1.divide((double)b2));
System.out.println(b3);
```

Comment: compile error *The method divide(BigInteger) in the type BigInteger is not applicable for the arguments (double)*

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger's divide method returns a BigInteger whose value is {@code (this / val)}.Y

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are indeed using `BigDecimal` (and not `BigInteger`): A `BigDecimal` is meant to provide a precise decimal value in a way that floating point cannot.  However, when dividing 22/7, that has a repeating decimal and thus cannot be represented as-is in a `BigDecimal`.

In this case, you need to specify to how many decimal places you wish to round, and how you wish to round (up, down, or nearest).  So to round to three decimal places, you will want:

```
BigDecimal b3 = b1.divide(b2, 3, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you were seeing for BigDecimal is explained well here:
[ArithmeticException: "Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591206/arithmeticexception-non-terminating-decimal-expansion-no-exact-representable)

By adding precision and rounding off, the issue can be handled.
    a.divide(b, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
where 2 is precision and RoundingMode.HALF_UP is rounding mode.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Your current code with BigIntegers works on Java7.

And to save the result in a double for both BigDecimal and BigInteger:

```
double b4 = b1.divide(b2,2).doubleValue();
double b4 = b1.divide(b2).doubleValue();
```

So,
BigDecimal:

```
BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal("22");
BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal("7");
BigDecimal b3 = b1.divide(b2,2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
double b4 = b1.divide(b2,2).doubleValue();
double b5 = b1.divide(b2,2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
```

BigInteger:

```
 BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("22");
 BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger("7");
 BigInteger b3 = b1.divide(b2);
 double b4 = b1.divide(b2).doubleValue();
```

Answer (score -1):

Since **big integers** are thought for **BIG NUMBERS** dont use double (maybe it too big for 64 bits space...) instead use BigDecimal which can take in the constructor a BigInteger too:

```
BigDecimal b3 = new BigDecimal("22").divide(new BigDecimal("7"), 3, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

System.out.println(b3);

Comment: It will truncate the decimal points. It output `3` whereas it should be `3.14285...`.

Comment: please accept one answer that suited best for your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how to get double value,

```
BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("22");
BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger("7");
double b3 = b1.divide(b2).doubleValue();
System.out.println(b3);
```