# Divide two BigInt values and cast the result to Float in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame which contains two columns of type **BigInt**. Then I have a user-defined function which performs an operation over these two columns and the final result is supposed to be of type **Float**.

```
def generateNewColumnValue(firstColumnValue: BigInt, secondColumnValue: BigInt): Float = {
   val calculated = scala.math.pow(firstColumnValue.toFloat / secondColumnValue, 1.0/3.0);
   return calculated;
}

val generateNewColumnValueUDF = udf[Float, BigInt, BigInt](generateNewColumnValue);
```

Inside of the body of the UDF I am doing some very simple calculations, as you can see. The problem is that I get the following error and I don't understand why it is not possible:

```
command-836521033094408:9: error: overloaded method value / with alternatives:
  (x: Double)Double <and>
  (x: Float)Float <and>
  (x: Long)Float <and>
  (x: Int)Float <and>
  (x: Char)Float <and>
  (x: Short)Float <and>
  (x: Byte)Float
 cannot be applied to (BigInt)
  val calculated = scala.math.pow(firstColumnValue.toFloat / secondColumnValue, 1.0/3.0);
```

The problem is that if I try to cast it to a lower range type (like Int) I might be losing some value after the decimal point.

Comment: `new BigDecimal(firstColumnValue).divide(secondColumnValue, roundingMode).toFloat` (or better .toDouble if you can)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In java, how do I divide two BigIntegers and store the value in a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39762172/in-java-how-do-i-divide-two-bigintegers-and-store-the-value-in-a-double)

Comment: @Thilo BigInteger is not part of Scala. I tried with BigInt but it doesn't work.

Comment: For Scala `BigDecimal` you write `BigDecimal(firstColumnValue)`, no `new` (and divide with `/`, not `divide`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message just says you can divide a `Float` by `Double`, `Float`, etc. but not by `BigInt`. Call `toFloat` on both operands, not just one:

```
firstColumnValue.toFloat / secondColumnValue.toFloat
```

But `math.pow` takes `Double`s, not `Float`s, so `toDouble` makes more sense. 
If the result has to be `Float`, call `toFloat` on the result of `pow`, not its arguments.

Or going through `BigDecimal`:

```
(BigDecimal(firstColumnValue) / BigDecimal(secondColumnValue)).toDouble
```

In most cases it should give approximately the same result as the first option, but slower; the problem is that `BigInt`s can be so large that `firstColumnValue.toDouble` returns `Double.PositiveInfinity`/`NegativeInfinity`. You could check for that, and only use the second option in that case.