# Java BigDecimal Problems (String to BigDecimal - BigDecimal to String)

Tags: java, android, parsing, bigdecimal

I know, there are dozens of topic like this in site but I am having trouble with 3 problems and I couldnt figure out all of them at the same time.

Actually, I am trying to make a calculator for **Android** but sometimes I cannot get what I am expected to.

A part of my code is;

```
}else if(operator.equals("/")){

            if(resultScreen.indexOf("/")==0){
                strNum2 = resultScreen.substring(resultScreen.indexOf("/")+1,resultScreen.length());
                intNum1 = result;
            }else{
                strNum1 = resultScreen.substring(0,resultScreen.indexOf("/"));
                strNum2 = resultScreen.substring(resultScreen.indexOf("/")+1,resultScreen.length());
                intNum1 = new BigDecimal(strNum1);
            }

            intNum2 = new BigDecimal(strNum2);


            if(intNum2.equals(0)){
                tvScreen.setText("Err");
                resultScreen ="";
            }else{
                result = intNum1.divide(intNum2);

                resultScreen = result.toString();

                tvScreen.setText(resultScreen);
                resultScreen ="";
            }
        }
```

When I try to;

> 22/7

It comes up;

> 3

How can I fix that?

By the way, I want to keep the exact value of decimal.

Comment: Please read the javadoc about divide: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html (and see https://ideone.com/Fd197W)

Comment: I think its a duplicate of this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591206/arithmeticexception-non-terminating-decimal-expansion-no-exact-representable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("22");
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("3");
    BigDecimal res = a.divide(b, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(res);
```

The key thing is to have a roundingMode else if the value can not be represented exactly an Exception will be thrown.

Comment: BigDecimal res = a.divide(b, 9, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); 

this makes better. Thank you.