# Error while dividing BigDecimal value : java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591206/arithmeticexception-non-terminating-decimal-expansion-no-exact-representable) and did rounding of `BigDecimal` value then also I am getting above mentioned error. Please find code mentioned below. Thanks in advance:

```
BigDecimal val1 = new BigDecimal(494.10000001).setScale(8, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
BigDecimal val2 = new BigDecimal(693189.38625000).setScale(8, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
BigDecimal result = val1.divide(val2);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: try BigDecimal result=val1.divide(val2,8,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

Comment: The post you linked mentions `a.divide(b, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)`, but that's not what you're doing, so I'm inclined to say this is just a duplicate of that, or a typographical error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer was in that post, and stated multiple time also:

```
a.divide(b, 8, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

try this for your divide statement, (the scale is 8 for your precision).
What you're doing right now is dividing two large decimals, which results in an ultra large decimal answer, and you're not controlling the precision.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the **divide** method has its own optional rounding mode parameter:

```
BigDecimal result=val1.divide(val2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
```