# How to collect element of the stream into groups of fixed size in accordance with their order

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to do the following with a `Stream<BigDecimal>` using Java 8 but am stuck at **step 2**.

1. Remove `null` and *negative values*.
2. Create groups with a size of **3** elements. Retain groups with an average of less than **30**, otherwise discard.

Example. Let's assume the following:

```
stream<Bigdecimal> input = {4,5,61,3,9,3,1,null,-4,7,2,-8,6,-3,null}; //technically its incorrect but just assume.
```

I was able to solve **step 1** as below:

```
Stream<BigDecimal> newInList = input.filter(bd -> (bd != null && bd.signum() > 0));
```

I'm not able to do the **step 2** - create groups of 3 elements.

The expected result for **step2**: `{4,5,6},{61,3,9},{3,1,7}`.

I'm looking for a solution with Java 8 streams.

Comment: Lets take this example: stream<Bigdecimal> input = {4,5,6,61,3,9,3,1,null,-4,,7,2,-8,6,-3,null};
after step1 input = {4,5,6,61,3,9,3,1,7,2,6,}; 
step2: pair of 3 => {4,5,6},{61,3,9},{3,1,7},{2,6}; 
 So adding values in each pair will be 15, 73, 11 (since last{2,6} is not a pair of 3 its discarded). 
average of of above added values = 15/3 , 73/3, 11/3 => 5, 24.3,3.3. 
these are less than 30, so need to retain the paired values => {4,5,6},{61,3,9},{3,1,7} and return these values as Stream<BigDecimal> something like {4,5,6,61,3,9,3,1,7}.

Comment: Please, **copy this example to your question** so that everyone can see it. And also substitute the word `pair` with `group of 3 elements. Because `pair means 2`.

Comment: By the way, "Remove null and negative values" implies keeping zeros, so `filter(bd -> bd != null && bd.signum() >= 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to extract **groups with the size of 3 elements** from the stream in accordance with their order.

It can be done using *Stream API* by implementing a **custom collector** that implements the [**Collector**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html) interface.

While initializing the `GroupCollector` size of the group has to be provided (it's was done to make the collector more flexible and avoid hard-coding the value of `3` inside the class).

`Deque<List<T>>` is used as a mutable container because the `Deque` interface provides convenient access to the last element.

`combiner()` method provides the logic of how to combine results of the execution obtained by different threads. **Parallel stream** provides a *guarantee* for the `collect()` operation that the initial order of the stream will be preserved and results from the different threads will be joined with respect to the order they were assigned with their tasks. Therefore this solution can be parallelized.

The logic of combining the two **queues** produced by different treads entails the following concerns:

- make sure that all groups (except for one that should be the last) have exactly `3` elements. Therefore we can't simply add all the contents of the *second deque* to the *first deque*. Instead, every group of the *second deque* has to be processed one by one.
- lists that are already created *should be reused*.

`finisher()` function will discard the last *list* in the *deque* if its size is less than the `groupSize` (requirement provided by the PO in the comment).

As an example, I've used the sequence of numbers from the question.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<BigDecimal> source =
                IntStream.of(4, 5, 6, 61, 3, 9, 3, 1, 7, 2, 6)
                .mapToObj(BigDecimal::valueOf);

        System.out.println(createGroups(source)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())); // collecting to list for demonstration purposes
    }
```

Method **createGroups()**

```
    public static Stream<List<BigDecimal>> createGroups(Stream<BigDecimal> source) {
        return source
                .collect(new GroupCollector<BigDecimal>(3))
                .stream()
                .filter(list -> averageIsLessThen(list, 30));
    }
```

**Collector**

```
    public class GroupCollector<T> implements Collector<T, Deque<List<T>>, Deque<List<T>>> {
        private final int groupSize;

        public GroupCollector(int groupSize) {
            this.groupSize = groupSize;
        }

        @Override
        public Supplier<Deque<List<T>>> supplier() {
            return ArrayDeque::new;
        }

        @Override
        public BiConsumer<Deque<List<T>>, T> accumulator() {
            return (deque, next) -> {
                if (deque.isEmpty() || deque.getLast().size() == groupSize) {
                    List<T> group = new ArrayList<>();
                    group.add(next);
                    deque.addLast(group);
                } else {
                    deque.getLast().add(next);
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public BinaryOperator<Deque<List<T>>> combiner() {
            return (deque1, deque2) -> {
                if (deque1.isEmpty()) {
                    return deque2;
                } else if (deque1.getLast().size() == groupSize) {
                    deque1.addAll(deque2);
                    return deque1;
                }
                // last group in the deque1 has a size less than groupSize
                List<T> curGroup = deque1.pollLast();
                List<T> nextGroup;
                for (List<T> nextItem: deque2) {
                    nextGroup = nextItem;
                    Iterator<T> iter = nextItem.iterator();
                    while (iter.hasNext() && curGroup.size() < groupSize) {
                        curGroup.add(iter.next());
                        iter.remove();
                    }
                    deque1.add(curGroup);
                    curGroup = nextGroup;
                }
                if (curGroup.size() != 0) {
                    deque1.add(curGroup);
                }
                return deque1;
            };
        }

        @Override
        public Function<Deque<List<T>>, Deque<List<T>>> finisher() {
            return deque -> {
                if (deque.peekLast() != null && deque.peekLast().size() < groupSize) {
                    deque.pollLast();
                }
                return deque;
            };
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }
    }
```

The *auxiliary method* that is used to validate a **group** of elements based on its *average value* (*in case you are wondering what `RoundingMode` is meant for, then read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4591216/17949945)*).

```
    private static boolean averageIsLessThen(List<BigDecimal> list, double target) {
        BigDecimal average = list.stream()
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
                .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(list.size()), RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        return average.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(target)) < 0;
    }
```

**output** (*expected result:* { **4, 5, 6, 61, 3, 9, 3, 1, 7** }, provided by the PO)

```
[4, 5, 6, 61, 3, 9, 3, 1, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander for your quick response. I wrote the Step2 as below though its not fully per java8 but can you suggest if this can be reduced to 8 standards. I am not sure how it will behave on performance and speed but.....

Comment: @Praveen `reduced to 8 standards` - only Java 8 features are used in the code above. `performance and speed` - this solution has minimal possible time complexity for this problem.